# Where is it possible to download some sample applications for jboss eap?

Tags: deployment, jboss, rhel, sample

I have just started working with jboss eap 7 application servers, so I would like to have an environment where I can carry out various tests, I have created a small laboratory with standalone and cluster included, but I would like to have some applications where I can test deployments, status monitoring and the server logs and the applications, I have a graylog for that purpose of the logs, but I just need the ear war applications etc... where could I download some sample applications to deploy in my laboratory?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You should use JBoss EAP QuickStarts https://github.com/jboss-developer/jboss-eap-quickstarts